# What's the query to get a list of a user's own posts that they have Liked?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Yes, I know that it's unusual for a user to "like" their own posts but that's what I'm looking for. I also know that you can't query the like table by user to get everything they've liked but that's not what I'm after. I just want their own posts (and later, photos) that they've liked.

I've clearly gotten pathetically rusty in my SQL skills--playing around with statements based off of the examples I've found:

```
SELECT source_id,message,created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id=me()
```

and

```
SELECT actor_id, post_id, message FROM stream WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM like WHERE uid1=me())
```

I imagine what I want is either trivial to do or currently impossible. I expect the former.

Answer (score 0):

To get the post ids that the user likes, it would be something like:

```
SELECT post_id 
FROM like 
WHERE object_id in (SELECT source_id FROM stream WHERE source_id=me())
AND user_id = me()
```

You could expand this to also include photo ids.  And you could nest it another level deep to get more post info by using the like's post_id field.